Why doesn't 'export' give the export attribute while 'set -a' does?
From man bash (GNU bash, version 5.2.21(1)-release (x86_64-pc-cygwin)):
set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [--] [-] [arg ...]
  -a  Each variable or function that is created or modified is given the export
      attribute and marked for export to the environment of subsequent commands.

export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...
export -p
      The supplied names are marked for automatic export to the environment of
      subsequently executed commands.

Here we see that export doesn't "give the export attribute" while set -a does. Why? Is it an oversight?
Extra question: what's the difference between "export" and "automatic export"? (Should both be "export"? Should both be "automatic export"?)

Are you sure it doesn't? Did you try comparing the output of declare -p variable with one exported via set -a and one exported via export?

@muru In man bash I see that description of export doesn't contain "give the export attribute" (or similar) text. In other words: man bash says that set -a does A and B, while export does B. Hence, I'm wondering why doesn't export do A OR is it an oversight in man bash and export does A as well.

Yes, I got that. My question: did you actually test it?

Re: "did you actually test it": no. I expect that to know what the command does it should be sufficient to read the manual for that command. While working with standards (e.g. Standard C) I tend to expect manuals to be precise and consistent.

Ah, I remember hearing somewhere: "In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is." That's a flawed expectation you have, (a reasonable thing to desire, yes, but you should be well aware by now that not even the C standard has always been perfectly consistent).

@pmor, note that you're not reading a standards document here, just the documentation of Bash, which is just one implementation of a POSIX-compatible shell among others.

If you want to check the POSIX standard, it says of export that "The shell shall give the export attribute to the variables corresponding to the specified names" and of set -a that "When this option is on, the export attribute shall be set for each variable to which an assignment is performed;"

@ilkkachu Yes, the documentation of Bash is not a standard. I'm OK with that. Yes, the C standard is not perfectly consistent. For example, I've found (by grepping the PDF) that some wordings are not consistent and proposed to fix that.

It's the one and same export attribute, just the help texts there aren't too consistent with each other. The export attribute is how the shell marks variables for (automatic) export.
export gives the attribute to the specified variables, while set -a gives it to any and all variables on assignment.

We can check the value and attributes of the named variable with declare -p var. Here we see that both export and set -a give the same export (-x) flag:
$ foo=123
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo="123"
$ export foo
$ declare -p foo
declare -x foo="123"

$ set -a
$ bar=456
$ declare -p bar
declare -x bar="456"


If I had to guess why the help text says "automatic export" there, I'd figure it refers to the alternative of "manually" exporting the variables through assignments at the start of the command, e.g. here, neither var needs to have the export flag:
$ somevar=123
$ othervar=456
$ somevar=$somevar othervar=999 env | grep -E 'somevar|othervar'
othervar=999
somevar=123


Thanks. Does `given the export attribute" imply "marked for export to the environment of subsequent commands"? In other words: is it possible to give the export attribute w/o marking for export to the environment of subsequent commands?

@pmor, that's what I was trying to say, it's one and single thing. The export attribute is the way the shell marks variables for export to the environment of subsequently launched commands.

Do you think that man bash needs to be updated: for both export  and set -a it should say (for example) "it gives the export attribute (which causes marking for (automatic) export to the environment...)"?

Is it possible to give export attribute to variables ans functions declared before set -a?

@pmor sure: foo=bar; export foo (which, IIRC, is required in old Bourne shells that don't support export foo=bar), or foo () ...; export -f foo

@muru OK (I'm aware of this method). Rephasing the question: is it possible to give export attribute to variables and functions declared before set -a at once? In other words, giving export attribute via export (-f) foo is time consuming because there may be many variables ad functions. And the second question: is it possible to temporarily give export attribute to (already declared) variables and functions? Example: foo(){ <export_all_vars_and_funcs> <some_code_which_uses_exported_vars_and_funcs> <un-export_all_vars_and_funcs> }.

@pmor, as far as I know: probably not, and probably not. Then again, wanting to export everything seems a bit odd, mostly because that would include variables that really only make sense within the shell (say, PS4, and Bash's RANDOM...). Everything set up somewhere else should be marked as exported there, and wihtin a script, you can just set -a at the start if you need to export everything you set there. I wonder, what is your use case here?

1/2 Thanks. Yes, it seems a bit odd. My use case is using GNU parallel and/or xargs -P with exported Bash functions. The top-level (Bash) functions (i.e. which are passed to parallel and/or xargs -P) can be easily located in the code and exported manually (via export -f foo). However, these top-level functions may call other functions (and/or use variables), which may call other functions (and/or use variables), etc. Hence, there is a need to find all the functions and variables, which may be used by the top-level functions.

2/2 This may be time-consuming. Hence, I do set -a at the beginning of the script, which may be sub-optimal. Hence, I wondered whether it is possible to temporarily give export attribute to (already declared) variables and functions. Is set -a at the beginning of the script considered OK?
